# Is 'ftell()' return value guaranteed to be larger when more characters have been read?

Tags: c, gcc, ftell

I understand, after a careful reading of [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com)'s C library reference that
"*For text streams, the numerical value* [returned by ftell()] *may not be meaningful*"

My question is: Does this mean that I can't be **absolutely** sure that the value returned when I have, say, read 3000 characters will be larger than the one returned when only 3 characters have been read?

Thanks in advance,

João Silva.

Comment: If you want to know the absolute offset of a file stream, in bytes, you can `fflush()` it and then use the _POSIX_ function `lseek()` (with a _whence_ of `SEEK_CUR` and an _offset_ of 0, and a _filedes_ given by the POSIX `fileno()` function using your stream handle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C standard:

> **7.21.9.4 The `ftell` function**
>   *Synopsis*
>   `#include <stdio.h>`
>   `long int ftell(FILE *stream);`
>   *Description*
>   The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the ﬁle position indicator for the stream
>   pointed to by stream. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from
>   the beginning of the ﬁle. **For a text stream, its ﬁle position indicator contains unspeciﬁed
>   information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the ﬁle position indicator for the
>   stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such
>   return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written
>   or read.**

(Emphasis mine)

I think it's pretty clear, but if not, leave a comment.

Comment: +1 Clear answer backed by the most legitimate source avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If `ftell()`'s numerical value isn't meaningful, then the relationship between two such values is also not meaningful.  Presumably the wording of the library documentation allows for file systems that use some form of internal records that may not be numbered in increasing order.

OTOH, I haven't seen a system where the value isn't a byte offset from the file start.  On some systems *(like Windows and DOS), there is an adjustment for two-character line endings.

Comment: It may, however be MORE than the number of bytes you've stored in your buffer, because the C library decides to translate CR/LF combination into a single `'\n'` combination. In fact it SHOULD do that.

Answer (score 0):

No. It means that e.g. the value returned by `ftell` *for text streams* when the file position ist at the end of a file may not be the actual number of bytes in the file. This is due to different line ending conventions and how these are treated on input. So in essence, you shouldn't do math with `ftell` values, like subtract them from each other, not even subtract 0 in the hope to compute the number of bytes from the beginning of the file to the current position.

It means that the value returned is only suitable to *reposition the file position* indicator to the same position is was obtained at.